# Loopback - API Connect - Licensing

Tags: ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop, apiconnect

My question: Can I use API Connect to develop loopback models for free, similar to how SLC ARC works?

I've been playing around with strongloop's ARC and it is fairly straightforward to discover models from a database schema. IBM is pushing API Connect and SLC ARC has a number of deficiencies (how it handles mssql schemas during discovery, the fact that custom connectors are not picked up and must be baked into ARC's source code, etc. that are unlikely to be addressed as ARC is no longer supported).

The Loopback.io homepage explicitly states that:

> A free version of API Connect especially for developers is available
>   called API Connect Essentials.

However, to run apic edit I am forced to sign up for Bluemix. On the registration page, it appears that I am receiving only a trial.

> Your 30-day trial is free, with no credit card required. You get
>   access to 2 GB of runtime and container memory to run apps, unlimited
>   IBM services and APIs, and complimentary support.

I don't care about online services or deploying my API to the cloud. I'd like to run loopback on my own servers and am simply planning to use API Connect for model generation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Loopback customer support. This question should be directed at them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing and asking for alternative solutions.

Comment: @gunr2171 I respectfully accept your decision, though hate how rigid SO is about this stuff.

Comment: For the record, an answer here was [picked up by a spam bot](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33858463#33858463), which is where the attention came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trial is for Bluemix itself, which allows you to use a variety of services for free for a period of time.

The API Connect Developer Toolkit is free to use regardless of your Bluemix account type.